# How i work out a probability when working with multiple number addition to work out rate of conflict

Tags: probability

So working on a system with someone else who made a mistake of building a personal identifier from 2 real numbers being added together, and in showing this I got asked what is the probability of collision and I'm unsure how I work it out.

So while this is a Maths question it does overlap with Comp Sci,

So Comp bit `Longs` are a real number from `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` in our case they are never going to be less than `0` so I have a range of `0-9,223,372,036,854,775,807` on two vars,

E.G

```
x = R{0, ..., 9223372036854775807}
y = R{0, ..., 9223372036854775807}
z = x+y
```

So could someone show me how I would work out the probability of collision on z?

Comment: How do you handle $z>9223372036854775807$? Does it wrap around to negative?

Comment: Your limiting number is $2^{63}-1$.  Are you really dealing with $64$ bit integers, not floats?  You keep talking of real numbers, which I had assumed were floats.  Are you asking that if $x,y$ are chosen randomly and $z=x+y$ computed, then $s,t$ are chosen randomly and $u=s+t$ what is the chance $u=z?$

Comment: @RossMillikan sorry it's using Long which is int64, with a whole number I suppose they are also real number's. But no I'm asking what is are the odds that either of the 2 numbers (seemingly) random added together will match E.G `8654564598865 + 1345435401134 = 9999999999999` and `8451742377451 + 1548257622548 = 9999999999999` i need to know what is the probability that collision will occur so `x + y` would equal the same as another `x+y`

Comment: @InterstellarProbe no, they will trigger a failure due to no carry or overflow bit space as that would become 65 bits in length and unable to be read or wrote as standard in the system I'm using.

Comment: @MartinBarker So, half of all IDs that are attempted to get created will result in a failure? That seems... less than ideal.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe yeah, I thought it would be that I just needed to understand the maths to prove it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple approach is to allow negative values and assume that the addition is carried out wrapping around, so if the sum is greater than $2^{63}-1$ it becomes negative and the sum of two large negative numbers becomes positive.  This is equivalent to addition $\bmod 2^{64}$.  If $x,y,s,t$ are chosen and $z=x+y, u=s+t$ are computed, to have $z=u$ we must have $x+y-s=t$.  There is precisely one value of $t$ out of $2^{64}$ that makes a collision, so the chance is $1$ in $2^{64}$.

Restricting to positive values cuts the number of choices for each variable to $2^{63}$.  The requirement that $t=x+y-s$ remains, but now cannot be satisfied if the required $t$ is less than $0$ or greater than $2^{63}-1$.  Once $x,y,s$ are chosen the chance is either $1$ in $2^{63}$ or zero, which I think is good enough for what you need.

Comment: This approach is much easier. I think you get the same results with my approach, but in a much more convoluted way.

Comment: Just a note I'm not able to allow negative values while they are seemingly random to my algorithm they are not they are generated and provided to me.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but it made a cleaner answer. I wanted to show it because it shows the logic nicely.